# How to shutdown Perl dancer applications nicely

Tags: perl, apache, signals, fastcgi, dancer

I run several Perl dancer applications at the same time with the same user in FCGI mode (Apache). As I understand correctly, Apache (or any other webserver) will fork a new dancer application if the current one(s) are busy.

To ensure that no visitor is interrupted by the dancer shutdown I like to let dancer handles the current connection until it finished and then `exit`/`last` the process.

How to shutdown a Perl dancer application using kill signal `HUP` to perfom such nice shutdown?

To rollout a new version of a dancer application I use `pkill -HUP perl` as the dancer user to "shutdown" the processes. But currently (due to missing signal handler) it's more like *shoot 'em down* as of *shutdown an application*.

Comment: If you are able to change your infrastructure you could try one of the plack webservers that support your need. [starman](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?starman) and [hyponotoad](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Mojo%3A%3AServer%3A%3AHypnotoad) both do graceful restarts on `SIGHUP`

Comment: `starman` sounds great, I try to argue with the sysadmins. May you want to make your comment an answer, @mugen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [solution by mugen kenichi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12989475/how-to-shutdown-perl-dancer-applications-nicely/13011436#comment17620439_12989475) works (`starman`):

> If you are able to change your infrastructure you could try one of the plack webservers that support your need. starman and hyponotoad both do graceful restarts on SIGHUP

There are a few shortcoming regarding `<% request.uri_base %>` so we have to develop with hard coded URI paths. Not very handsome but necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question correctly, you are concerned that Apache/FCGI might kill the Dancer app while it is in the middle of handling a request.  Is that correct?

If so, don't worry about it.  Apache/FCGI doesn't do that.  When it forks a new instance of the handler because existing ones are busy, that's a new one *in addition to* the existing instances.  The existing ones are left alone to finish what they're doing.

Comment: Hi @Dave. I have improve my question. It's not my concern that Apache is killing application wildly. But thanks anyway :)